# For loop not working in c

Tags: c, for-loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(){
    char x[9];
    for(i=0; i<=8; i++){
        printf("\nEnter your guess: ");
        scanf("%c", &x[i]);
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this code? When I enter the value for x[i], the loop runs for two times before letting me enter the value for x[i+1]. Someone please solve this out. I know its a simple error(not sure) but this is bugging the crap out of me.

Comment: What happens when `i` is 9?

Comment: @Subham Kharel Change the for loop or the programming language.:)

Comment: nah, thats nothing.. just assume that 'i<=9' is in the second parameter of the loop.

Comment: when will the loop end? never, is that intended, because in that case you will need an infinitely large array, which of course cannot exist.

Comment: @lhoworko yeah dude!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scanf(" %c", &x[i]);
```

Note the space before `%c`. This space will make sure the newline character is ignored.

When you enter a character and press enter there is a newline character in the buffer which will be picked up in the next iteration. So you need to ignore it by doing as shown above.

Comment: An explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: @haccks Added a short explanation that should be fine isn't it?

Comment: @Gopi; Much better now.